# comparing values using nested logical operators

Tags: jquery

I try to compare values in select list like this but it is not working. First I get already selected value and compare it to new value. So, if set value is x and newly selected value is not xxx or ccc, show message. I choose IS NOT operator because there are many more values.

```
var orig_status = $("#edit-status").val();

$("#edit-status").change(function () {

      if ((orig_status = 'pending') && (
           $('#edit-status').val() != 'xxx' ||
           $('#edit-status').val() != 'ccc'
         ))
          {
                   alert('upsss');             
      }
```

Basically , I want to make a simple check, while changing order statuses. For example if an order has status pending, then the normal workflow should be order_sent. If other option is selected, I want to display message.

The code works only if I do not use OR operator.Why is that?

http://jsfiddle.net/pDNJX/1/

What would be the best way to make it work? I use jquery 1.3.2
Thank you

Comment: Could you give more of a concrete example for what the comparisons are?

Comment: You might want to use == instead of just one =. (orig_status = 'pending')

Comment: @JohnBoker not working even with == please see jsfiddle

Comment: won't this always evaluate to true? `(some_condition AND (mutually_exclusive_condition OR mutually_exclusive_condition) )`  The OR statement will always evaluate to true because one being false necessitates that the other is true.

Comment: I agree with @JosephMarikle.  You need to look at your logic a little more closely.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Ok I understand, but how to do it then?

Comment: I suppose you want `… && !(a==b || a==c)` or `… && a!=b && a!=c`

Comment: @Bergi yes, that was it. thank you. Where I give you points?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OR conditions will always return a true value, use the below

```
  if ((orig_status == 'pending') && !(
              ($('#edit-status').val() == 'payment_received_trustpay' ||
              $('#edit-status').val() == 'odlozena_tovar'
             )))
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pDNJX/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you're misunderstanding the OR operator.  You say "if set value is x and newly selected value is not xxx or ccc".  A better way to word it would be "if set value is x and newly selected value is not xxx and newly selected value is not ccc".  With that in mind you can see that it should go `if (set_value = x && newly_selected_value != xxx && newly_selected_value != ccc)`.  Taking that logic and using your variable names, you can write it like this:

```
if (orig_status == 'pending' &&
    $('#edit-status').val() != 'xxx' &&
    $('#edit-status').val() != 'ccc'
) {
    alert('upsss');             
}
```

no need for more specificity than that.

edit:
and of course, if you want nicer, more efficient code, you should store that jQuery object in a variable rather than recreating it constantly.  If you have a huge list of values that you need to check against, you should use something like `.indexOf` and test if the return equals -1